# How to use substr() to remove NA in mpg$trans data

Tags: r

Turn the variable trans to a factor variable, of which unique values are “auto” and “manu” (Hint: use the function substr() to extract substrings in a character vector before converting to a factor vector)

```
unique(mpg$trans)
mpg$trans <- substr(mpg$trans, 1, 234)
mpg$trans <- factor(mpg$trans, levels = c("auto", "manu"))
str(mpg)
```

However, trans still doesn't work.

Comment: Compare output of `substr('abcde', 1, 3)` and `substr('abcde', 1, 4)`. When you are doing `mpg$trans <- substr(mpg$trans, 1, 234)` you are asking it to subset from position 1 to position 234 which does not exist.

Comment: `levls <- unique(substr(mpg$trans, 1, 4)); mpg$trans <- factor(mpg$trans, levels = levls)`.